# Is there a way to get a web page and apply it a javascript command like in chrome console from cpp or bash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, c++, bash

Is there a way ( library or program ) to download the result of a web page (like `curl or wget`) where you can just apply some javascript the same way you could on chrome's *developer tools* from cpp or bash ?

The goal would be to use it with jQuery's selectors (admitting said website uses jQuery. Or better, to add jQuery to the processed html to be able to process it that way)

I haven't found anything on the subject on google.

I'm not really sure if I made myself clear, so i'll provide an exemple.

For instance let's say I want to get this question's ([How to undo last commit(s) in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-last-commits-in-git)) accepted answer's code, it'd do

```
content = page.apply_js("$('div.accepted-answer pre code').text()");
```

and it would make `content` contain

```
$ git commit -m "Something terribly misguided"              (1)
$ git reset HEAD~                                           (2)
<< edit files as necessary >>                               (3)
$ git add ...                                               (4)
$ git commit -c ORIG_HEAD                                   (5)
```

I know that there are some shady details left unexplicited here, including type-correctness, but that is not the point.

Comment: Good question. Does it have to be javascript or could it be anything for manipulating XML?

Comment: I guess processing xml could certainly prouve useful, but i must admit I haven't made research over that area !

Comment: you could use something like the selenium project to automate code execution directly in a browser of your choice - idk if it's available for c++, but for Java and python it certainly is, here is a similar framework http://stackoverflow.com/q/17345551/3858121

Comment: that actually seems pretty convincing ! i didn't know the word "headless" for navigators !

Comment: jsdom is great for scraping websites and inculding additional third party scripts :-)

Comment: Have a look at [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org)