# C++ - Library to execute JavaScript in browser (IE 11 and Edge)

Tags: javascript, c++

I would like to know if the following is feasible in C++, and if so, what library / api would be required:

I want to launch a browser session from my C++ code (IE11 or Edge), and execute some JavaScript in the broswer from the C++ code. For example, launch https://stackoverflow.com and when users click on a button from my C++ GUI, display a JavaScript alert message.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345551/web-automation-from-c)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the "chromium embedded framework", google it to find it. This is not Microsoft stuff but who cares.

Comment: Also, [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/), and [Chrome DevTools automation API](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/).

Answer (score 0):

To clarify – your C++ code will need to launch a browser-object in a manner appropriate to *your* environment, and then feed it a block of HTML which includes appropriate `<script>` tags.  The browser instance, not your C++ code, is then responsible for "doing the right thing" from that point forward.

Answer (score 0):

Actually launching a browser depends on your operative system. You will need to launch a process associated with your browser, providing it some initialization flags (for example running a shell script like:

`open -a "Google Chrome" index.html`

In any case, you may want to investigate a little more about [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) or [Cheerp](https://www.leaningtech.com/cheerp/) that are tools that allow you to write C++ code and running it on the browser natively in Javascript (via Asm.js or Web Assembly