# Use selenium with C

Tags: c, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I can't find any information on if you can use selenium with C. Just C, not c#. Does anyone know if this is possible?

I tried searching on Google but all results that appear has "C#" in it and not "C".

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345551/web-automation-from-c

Answer (score 4):

From the [official page](https://selenium.dev/downloads/) of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491):

- The core language-specific client drivers are:
- **Ruby**
- **JavaScript**
- **Java**
- **Python**
- **C#**

---

However as per [Selenium Official Home Page](https://www.selenium.dev/ecosystem/) language bindings for other languages does exist but those projects are not supported, maintained, hosted, or endorsed by the Selenium project, which are as follows:

- [**Selenium** [Language: Go]](https://github.com/tebeka/selenium)
- [**hs-webdriver** [Language: Haskell]](https://github.com/kallisti-dev/hs-webdriver)
- [**wd** [Language: JavaScript]](https://github.com/admc/wd)
- [**Selenium-Remote-Driver** [Language: Perl]](https://github.com/teodesian/Selenium-Remote-Driver)
- [**php-webdriver** [Language: PHP]](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver)
- [**RSelenium** [Language: R]](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium)
- [**webdriver.dart** [Language: Dart]](https://github.com/google/webdriver.dart)

---

### Solution

You could always write your WebDriver based tests in any of the core language e.g. Java/Python/C# and call the script from your *C* / *C++* application.

---

### Webdriver++

[Webdriver++](https://github.com/durdyev/webdriverxx) is a C++ client library for Selenium Webdriver which you have to install and have the following feature support:

- Chainable commands
- Value-like objects compatible with STL containers
- Header-only
- Lightweight dependencies:
- libcurl
- picojson
- Can be used with any testing framework
- Linux, Mac and Windows
- clang (3.4), GCC (4.6) and Visual Studio (2010)

An example:

```
#include <webdriverxx/webdriverxx.h>
using namespace webdriverxx;

int main() {
    WebDriver firefox = Start(Firefox());
    firefox
    .Navigate("http://google.com")
    .FindElement(ByCss("input[name=q]"))
    .SendKeys("Hello, world!")
    .Submit();
    return 0;    
}
```

---

@JimEvans in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345551/web-automation-from-c/17346890#comment25183721_17346890) clearly mentions:

> If you really don't care that you're not running in a "real" browser, then directly consuming QtWebKit might be a good choice. Realize, though that it's not a trivial undertaking. There aren't any C++ language bindings for WebDriver, as far as I know, but as long as you have a JSON parsing library (json-cpp is pretty good), and an HTTP client library, you can write your own language bindings in pretty short order.

Comment: TLDR: bindings for 11 languages available, but none for C.